# Provide a list of data to "ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE"

Tags: mysql, sql

I have an array of data that I'd like to insert into a table.  The table has a unique key `code` and if a record already exists with that key I would like to update that record instead.  I thought that this might be achievable with the `INSERT INTO ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` statement

```
INSERT INTO codes (code, delta) 
VALUES ... 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
delta=new_delta
```

The problem with the above syntax is that `new_delta` is an attribute different for each cell in the array.  Is it possible to provide a list of each `new_delta` in this syntax, and select the relevant `new_delta` for each `code`?  Or is there another way that this problem should be approached?

Comment: What array?  MySQL does not have a data type called "array".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could but it's going to get really complex, unless I misunderstood.

This is the normal form:

```
INSERT INTO codes (code, delta) 
   VALUES (code1, delta1),
          (code2, delta2), 
           ....
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
    delta = VALUES(delta)
```

Here, if both code1 and code2 exist, the first will be updated to delta1, and the second to the values of delta2; because those are the `VALUES()` of the column called delta.

But it seems to me that you want to have a different delta? So you have (code1, delta1) in the database, you insert (code1, delta2), and if code1 already exists, the delta value should be set to delta3?

In this case you can do this:

```
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
    delta = CASE code
        WHEN code1 THEN delta3
        WHEN code2 THEN delta5
        ...
        END
```

Or you can add a new column to the database, dupdelta, with the same type of delta. Now you insert this tuple:

```
 (code3, delta3, delta4)
```

meaning: if code3 does not exist, you want to set its delta to delta3. But if it already exists, you want its delta to be delta4 instead.

You just specify

```
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE delta=VALUES(dupdelta)
```

Of course now the table has an extra useless column called dupdelta. You may want to create a VIEW to hide it.

Comment: Ahh thank you.  I didn't realize that the `INSERT` portion of the statement created a column of codes and deltas, and that those columns could be referenced.  I was thinking that the `INSERT` and `UPDATE` portions of the statement were sort of independent of each other.